# "compute_cluster_for_hadoop start" doesn't work with gcutil 1.10.0

Tags: google-compute-engine

**Update:** It looks like ./compute_cluster_for_hadoop.py works with gcutil 1.9.1 but not with gcutil 1.10.0. So what I am really asking is how to fix compute_cluster_for_hadoop to work with the current gcutil.

After using compute_cluster_for_hadoop.py for weeks, now starting a cluster hangs, even after I setup the cluster again.

Here are some things I noticed. First, I now get the following message when I run "compute_cluster_for_hadoop.py start ..." that I have to manually type in "yes" to (Before, it never required any user input).

> The authenticity of host
>   'google-compute-engine-instance;project=cspp53013;zone=us-central1-a;instance=hm;id=9724559583598617300
>   (8.35.196.11)' can't be established. ECDSA key fingerprint is
>   02:2b:ea:7d:48:27:7d:1b:e2:2a:d4:44:d0:07:95:b4. Are you sure you want
>   to continue connecting (yes/no)?

It then proceeds for a while. right after it finishes installing the deb_packages, it prints the following

> Processing triggers for ca-certificates ... Updating certificates in
>   /etc/ssl/certs... 0 added, 0 removed; done. Running hooks in
>   /etc/ca-certificates/update.d.... done. done.

And then it hangs no matter how long I wait.

Any idea what could have changed or how to fix?

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: BTW, Here's the traceback when I Ctrl-C out of the script: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xxx/compute_cluster_for_hadoop.py", line 223, in <module>
    main()
  File "xxx/compute_cluster_for_hadoop.py", line 219, in main
    ComputeClusterForHadoop().ParseArgumentsAndExecute(sys.argv[1:])
  File "xxx/compute_cluster_for_hadoop.py", line 215, in ParseArgumentsAndExecute
    params.handler(params)
  File "xxx/compute_cluster_for_hadoop.py", line 41, in Start
    gce_cluster.GceCluster(flags).StartCluster() - Continued in next comment

Comment: File "xxx/gce_cluster.py", line 324, in StartCluster
    self._Postprocess()
  File "xxx/gce_cluster.py", line 298, in _Postprocess
    self._WaitForInstancesReady()
  File "xxx/gce_cluster.py", line 191, in _WaitForInstancesReady
    if self._CheckSshReady(instance_name):
  File "xxx/gce_cluster.py", line 154, in _CheckSshReady
    if subprocess.call(command, shell=True):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 493, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
- Continued in next comment

Comment: File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1301, in wait
    pid, sts = _eintr_retry_call(os.waitpid, self.pid, 0)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 478, in _eintr_retry_call
    return func(*args)
KeyboardInterrupt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. Figured out the answer. We just have to add

> --ssh_arg "-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no"

to line 151 of gce_cluster.py and it works with both gcutil-1.9.1 and gcutil-1.10.0